# Firebase object download - android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class ShowRecipe extends AppCompatActivity {

private String recipeName;
private ArrayList<Recipe> lst=new ArrayList<Recipe>();
ProgressDialog pg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_recipe);
    getInfo();
    pg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "please wait", true);
    databasetry();
    init();
}


public void init() {
    TextView recipeNameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_recipe_TV);
    recipeNameTV.setText(""+lst.get(0).getRecipeName());

    CheckBox cosher = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxCosher_ShowRecipe);
    CheckBox peanutes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxPeanues_ShowRecipe);
    CheckBox gloten = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxGluten_ShowRecipe);

    Boolean c=lst.get(0).getCosher();
    Boolean p=lst.get(0).getPeanut();
    Boolean g=lst.get(0).getGluten();

    cosher.setChecked(c);
    peanutes.setChecked(p);
    gloten.setChecked(g);
}


private void getInfo() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        recipeName = extras.getString("recipeName");
    }
}

public void databasetry(){
    Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://recipe4u-f7470.firebaseio.com/");
    myFirebaseRef.child("Recipes").child(""+recipeName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Recipe currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Recipe.class);
            lst.add(currentUser);
            Toast.makeText(ShowRecipe.this, "Name:"+currentUser.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pg.dismiss();
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowRecipe.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

When i make a toast on the `databasetry()` action it gives me everything , when is save it as a list and use it in init action it gives me an error .

FYI : i want to download the object from the Firebase by his name (works) i download it to the `currentUser` (works) move to lst and toast toString() and than i want to use it in `init()` and it gives me an error . i can't solve it so if you can give me the solution or tips about the code .

Thanks you all guys and girls ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly it looks like you want to set a value in `onDataChange` then use that value in another block of code. If that's the case your challenge is that the call made to your `Firebase` database is asynchronous, which means that you can't be sure when `onDataChange` will be called and then know it is safe to use the value that was set in `onDataChange` .

Try moving your call to `init()` from `onCreate` to `onDataChange`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_recipe);
    getInfo();
    pg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "please wait", true);
    databasetry();
}

public void databasetry(){
    Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("yourFirebaseURL");
    myFirebaseRef.child("Recipes").child(""+recipeName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Recipe currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Recipe.class);
            lst.add(currentUser);
            Toast.makeText(ShowRecipe.this, "Name:"+currentUser.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pg.dismiss();
            init();
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowRecipe.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.